# Sessions Class (stored in table) not updating as expected

Tags: php, mysql, class, session, pdo

OK, I'm fully expecting someone to come along and tell me I missed something obvious, but I've spent days trying to figure out what's wrong, and I at this point, if someone can point out a stupid mistake, I'll just be glad to solve the problem. I'm just starting to figure out PDO, so I'm guessing the problem is there, but I really don't know.

This is mostly working. It opens, closes, reads, and does garbage collection. It will write, but only the id, not the data. Destroy is not working either, which seems to be related. If I put echo into the functions, the variables are being passed. The queries work when I try them directly. What seems to be happening is that the binding isn't working. I've tried both bindParam and bindValue. I've tried so many other things I can't even list them all. So anyway, here's the class:

```
class Sessions {
    private $id;
    private $data;
    protected $pdo;
    private $maxTime;
public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
    // Set handler to overide SESSION
    @session_set_save_handler(
            array($this, "openSession"),
            array($this, "closeSession"),
            array($this, "readSession"),
            array($this, "writeSession"),
            array($this, "destroySession"),
            array($this, "gcSession")
        );
    session_start();
}

public function openSession() 
{
  // If successful
  if ($this->pdo) {
     return true;
  } else {
     return false;
  }
}

public function closeSession() {
  // Close the database connection
  if ($pdo = NULL) {
     @session_write_close();
     return true;
  } else {
     return false;
   }
}

public function readSession($id) {
  if (isset($id)) {
     // Set query
     $q = 'SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = :id';
     $stmt = $this->pdo -> prepare($q);
     // Bind the Id
     $stmt -> bindValue(':id', $id);
     $stmt -> execute();
     $r = $stmt -> fetch();
     // Return the data
     if (!empty($r['data'])) {
        return $r['data'];
     } else {
        // Return an empty string
        return '';
     }
  } else {
     return '';
  }
}

// when session started and updated
public function writeSession($id, $data) {    
   // Set query
   $q = "INSERT INTO sessions 
                    (id, `data`, startTime) 
            VALUES (:id, :data, NOW()) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                `data` = :data2, 
                startTime = NOW()";  
   $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($q);            
   // Bind data
   $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
   $stmt->bindParam(':data', $data);
   $stmt->bindParam(':data2', $data);
   $stmt->execute();

   if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
      return TRUE;
   } else {
      return FALSE;
   }
 }// when session started and updated

public function writeSession($id, $data) {    
   // Set query
   $q = "INSERT INTO sessions (id, `data`, startTime) VALUES (:id, :data, NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `data` = :data2, startTime = NOW()";  
   $stmt = $this->pdo -> prepare($q);            
   // Bind data
   $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
   $stmt->bindParam(':data', $data);
   $stmt->bindParam(':data2', $data);
   $stmt->execute();
   if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
     return TRUE;
  } else {
     return FALSE;
  }
}

public function destroySession($id) {
    echo $id;
    $q = "DELETE FROM `sessions` WHERE `id`= :id";
    $stmt = $this->pdo -> prepare($q);
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    // Attempt execution
    if ($stmt === true) {
        echo " worked ";
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        echo " no ";
        return FALSE;
    }
}

public function gcSession($maxTime) {
   $q="DELETE FROM sessions WHERE (NOW()-startTime > $maxTime)";
   $stmt = $this->pdo -> prepare($q);
   if ($stmt->execute()) {
      return TRUE;
   } else {
      return FALSE;
   }
}
}
```

The function is being called this way:

```
     // Store the user in the session and redirect:
     $startSessions = new Sessions($pdo);
     $_SESSION['data'] = 'IDnotOK';
     $startSessions -> writeSession(session_id(), 'IDallOK');
     $startSessions -> gcSession(1800);
```

The 'IDnotOK' is being sent to the database (sort of - it's 'data|s:7:"IDnotOK";'), instead of 'IDallOK'. If the $_SESSION['data'] isn't there, nothing is sent at all. The id is passed just fine. The timestamp also updates just fine. When I call:

```
$startSessions -> destroySession(session_id());
```

it doesn't matter how I try to pass the id, it will echo from within the function, but won't do anything to the database entry. Garbage collections works (probably because it only relies on the time and doesn't care about the id).
I wish I could list everything I've tried, but I've lost track. If there are any other questions that will help track down the problem, please ask. Thank You!

Comment: If you manually write the sql string (without bidinding and stuff), just a straight hardcoded sql, does it work or still do just `id`?

Comment: $q = "INSERT INTO sessions (id, `data`, startTime) VALUES ($id, $data, NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `data` = $data, startTime = NOW()";  
         $stmt = $this->pdo -> prepare($q);            
         $stmt->execute();
Nothing is inserted at all.
If I change it to: 
         $q = "INSERT INTO sessions (id, `data`, startTime) VALUES ('longString1', 'longString2', NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `data` = 'longString3', startTime = NOW()";  
Both work (longString3 overwrites longString2). I can echo the id and data within the function, and they do show up on the page.

Comment: It occurred to me that perhaps being called after a form submission was the problem, so I tried adding the data as a hidden field, but that didn't work either. I am going to try it on the site live and see if that changes anything (working on XAMMP on my computer now).

Comment: That shouldn't matter. If you have it working with hardcoded value, then it should work with variables.

Comment: Further sleuthing. I found `$stmt->debugDumpParams();` and added that to the function, which output the query exactly as expected. So I double checked that I was using a username/password combo with delete available, which I was. So I'm completely stumped. All I can think now is that there's a problem with XAMPP. I'm going to put everything together as best I can with out testing, and then try it live on the website and see what happens. I just don't know where else to look at this point.

Comment: Further (frustrating) sleuthing. What is apparently happening is that the data is being entered, but then being overwritten and erased. `$startSessions = new Sessions($pdo);` writes the initial id and start time, and then `$startSessions -> writeSession(session_id(), 'IDallOK');` enters the data, and then somehow write is being called again, but without the data info, so it clears it out.

Comment: And the problem with delete is exactly the same. Delete removes the row, and then write puts it back. I don't see why write is being called again, but apparently it is.

Comment: You might want to do a debug_backtrace() and see if your method(s) are calling twice